# Program crashing near the end of compiling

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I've got a program for taking input and storing it into structs. The structs are for contact details, Name, Address, and Phone numbers. My program works just fine, I can enter all my information into the program however when I try to `printf` the results the program crashes halfway through. I think they may be an issue with memory or corruption, or something. The reason I think it may be with corruption is because if I cut off some of my program and compile it, instead of the program crashing I get a 'Run-Time check failure #2 Stack around the variable `'optionAddress'` was corrupted' error. Here's my program

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"
int main(void)
{
    // Declare variables here:

    struct Name names;
    char optionName;
    struct Address addresses;
    char optionAddress;
    struct Numbers number;
    char optionCell;
    char optionHome;
    char optionBusiness;

    // Display the title

    printf("Contact Management System\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    // Contact Name Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &names.firstName);
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionName);
    while (optionName == 'y' || optionName == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf("%s", &names.middleInitial);
        break;
    }
    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf("%s", &names.lastName);

    // Contact Address Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.streetNumber);
    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.street);
    printf("Do you want to enter an apartment number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionAddress);
    while (optionAddress == 'y' || optionAddress == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        scanf(" %c", &addresses.apartmentNumber);
        break;
    }
    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.postalCode);
    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf("%s", &addresses.city);

    // Contact Numbers Input:

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or no): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionCell);
    while (optionCell == 'y' || optionCell == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf(" %c", number.cell);
        break;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionHome);
    while (optionHome == 'y' || optionHome == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf(" %c", &number.home);
        break;
    }
    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%s", &optionBusiness);
    while (optionBusiness == 'y' || optionBusiness == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf(" %c", number.business);
        break;
    }

    // Display Contact Summary Details

    printf("Contact Details\n");
    printf("---------------\n");
    printf("Name Details\n");
    printf("First name: ");
    printf("%s", names.firstName);
    printf("\nMiddle initials(s): ");
    printf("%s", names.middleInitial);
    printf("\nLast name: ");
    printf("%s", names.lastName);
    printf("\n\nAddress Details\n");
    printf("Street number: ");
    printf("%s", addresses.streetNumber);
    printf("\nStreet name: ");
    printf("%s", addresses.street);
    printf("\nApartment: ");
    printf("%s", addresses.apartmentNumber);
    printf("\nPostal code: ");
    printf("%s", addresses.postalCode);
    printf("\nCity: ");
    printf("%s", addresses.city);
    printf("\n\nPhone Numbers: ");
    printf("\nCell phone number: ");
    printf("%s", number.cell);
    printf("\nHome phone number: ");
    printf("%s", number.home);
    printf("\nBusiness phone number: ");
    printf("%s", number.business);

    // Display Completion Message

    printf("\n\nStructure test for Name, Address, and Numbers Done!");

    return 0;
}
```

And the structs in the header file:

```
// Structure type Name declaration
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};

// Structure type Address declaration
// Place your code here...

 struct Address {
    char streetNumber;
    char street[41];
    char apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
 };

 // Structure type Numbers declaration
 // Place your code here...

 struct Numbers {
    char cell[21];
    char home[21];
    char business[21];   
 };
```

My program reaches the point of printing out `"Street number: "` then stops working. It is a windows error window that shows up, not a compiler window.

Comment: StreetNumber is char, but you input it as string: `scanf("%s", &addresses.streetNumber);`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  This causes the compiler to output 10 warnings, mostly about  the format string for calls to `scanf()` where the inputt/format specifier does not match the data to be set.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) When using the `%s` and/or the `%[...]` specifier, always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow with its' resulting undefined behavior and possible seg fault event.

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %c", &addresses.apartmentNumber);`  My apartment number is `764`  Which will not fit into a single character.  Infact almost all apartment numbers are multiple characters in length and can be things like: `22A` so are not strictly numeric.

Comment: regarding: `char postalCode[8];`  this is not long enough for many postal codes.  For instance in America, the postal code consists of a 5digit number, a space or dash, a 4digit number .  a 8 char field is only large enough for the 5digit number, the NUL terminator and 2 more characters.

Answer (score 2):

> My program reaches the point of printing out "Street number: " then
>   stops working.

Take a look at:

```
 struct Address {
    char streetNumber;    // declared as character!
    char street[41];
    char apartmentNumber; // character
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
 };

char optionName;
char optionAddress;
char optionCell;
char optionHome;
char optionBusiness;
```

Later on you try to read the values to the characters:

```
scanf("%s", &optionName);
scanf("%s", &optionAddress);
scanf("%s", &optionCell);
scanf("%s", &optionHome);
scanf("%s", &optionBusiness);

scanf("%s", &addresses.streetNumber); // <-------------- string read
```

using string format `%s`. That invokes UB since you are reading at least `2` bytes. `"y"` is a string with string null terminator `'\0'`. That extra byte overwrites the memory location.
Change declarations of variables to strings or reading format to character read as you already do here:

```
  scanf(" %c", &addresses.apartmentNumber);
```

Comment: As long as all street numbers are between `-128` and `127` he should be fine `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", &optionName);
```

This invites undefined behavior which could lead to run time error you are getting as `optionName` is `char` one byte and `scanf()` with %s will try to write `'\0'` which will surely go beyond bounds

Comment: I tried to make optionName[2] instead, however when I do that it makes the while loops for the options stop working and the program still crashes at the end. Should I be changing the optionName in another way?

Comment: You can keep optionName as char, and change scanf to     scanf(" %c", &optionName); so that it takes care of whitespace from prior scanf